# Setup Ingress-Nginx rate limit rps for a specific path

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am using Kubernetes Kops. I want to set rate limit rps at Ingress-Nginx level for a specific path only.

I know about

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps
```

If I set this in Ingress rules then it will be applicable for all the routes. But, I want to apply it for a specific route. Let's say, when I am trying to access

```
/login
```

I want to set rps limit to 100 for the path /login

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: 100
```

This is my Ingress rules config,

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: staging-ingress-rules
  namespace: staging
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'nginx'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: '0'
spec:
  rules:
  - host: staging.mysite.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /login
        backend:
          serviceName: login_site
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /registration
        backend:
          serviceName: registration_site
          servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to slightly abuse the config for ingress-nginx by adding multiple Ingress definitions for the same hostname. ingress-nginx will merge the rules/routes together. The config will become harder to manage though and you are getting towards the limits of what nginx proxying can do for you.

#### Other options

Traefik has a [rate limit middleware](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/middlewares/ratelimit/) that can be applied to [routes](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/middlewares/overview/).

Also look at something like [kong](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/rate-limiting/) or [istio](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limiting/) if you want to start managing individual services with more detail.

#### Nginx Ingress config

Creating a structure to your naming conventions will be important here so you know which Ingress houses which routes. Using the route path in the Ingress `name` is the where I would start but your use case may vary:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: staging-ingress-rules-registration
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'nginx'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: '0'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: '10'
spec:
  rules:
  - host: staging.mysite.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /registration
        backend:
          serviceName: registration-site
          servicePort: 80
```

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: staging-ingress-rules-login
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'nginx'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: '0'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: '100'
spec:
  rules:
  - host: staging.mysite.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /login
        backend:
          serviceName: login-site
          servicePort: 80
```

I'm not sure how host wide or server wide annotations (like [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-ciphers`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#ssl-ciphers)) would need to be managed. If they all merge nicely then maybe create a special Ingress just to house those. If not you might end up managing host settings across all Ingress configs which will be a pain.